# Leaflet custom coordinates grid?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

please tell me how to change the coordinate grid for the classic Leaflet (I use custom titles 256x256 if it’s important, this is a game map) so that the corners are:
Bottom left: -1,0
Top left: -1,1
Bottom Right: 0,0
Top right: 0,1

My current code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Your Map</title>
     <!-- Connecting the Leaflet library -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"/>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
     <style>
         #map {
             height: 500px;
         }
     </style>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="map"></div>
     <script>

         // Defining the coordinate transformation function
         function customTransformation(unprojectedPoint) {
             return new L.Point(unprojectedPoint.x - 1, -unprojectedPoint.y);
         }

         // Create a new coordinate system using your own transform function
         const customCRS = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
             transformation: new L.Transformation(1, 0, 1, 0),
             unproject: function (point) {
                 return this.transformation.untransform(point, this.scale).subtract([1, 0]);
             },
             project: function (latlng) {
                 return this.transformation.transform(latlng.add([1, 0]), this.scale);
             }
         });

         // Create a map with a new coordinate system
         const map = L.map('map', {
             minZoom: 3,
             maxZoom: 6,
             crs: customCRS,
         });

         // Add a layer of tiles using the standard EPSG:3857 projection
         const tileLayer = L.tileLayer('/HiRes/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
             minZoom: 3,
             maxZoom: 6,
             tileSize: 256,
             attribution: 'Your attribute',
             bounds: L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(-1, 0), L.latLng(0, 1)),
         });

         map.addLayer(tileLayer);

         // Set new map center and zoom
         const center = map.unproject([0, 0], map.getMaxZoom());
         map.setView(center, 3);

         // Add a marker to the specified coordinates
         const marker = L.marker([0.52005474202153, -0.47142937288154]).addTo(map);

         // Add a click event handler
         map.on('click', function (event) {
             const clickedLatLng = event.latlng;
             console.log('Click coordinates:', clickedLatLng.lat.toFixed(2), clickedLatLng.lng.toFixed(2));
         });

     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand how to make the map look the way I want...

Comment: You would need to show what you get vs what you want, as it's hard to see the issue. Maybe the leaflet documentation can help: https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html

Comment: @XaC I'm trying to override corner coordinates for a custom map.